# Integrating Artistic Style with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, formatting, astyle

Is it possible to integrate Artistic Style with Visual Studio 2010? It does a much better job of fixing mangled code indenting and styling than the include visual studio code formatter. Ideally a hotkey or something to apply it to the current file. I know how to apply it by hand but there must be a plugin or something available to help to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can add external tools to the IDE. See the Tools menu. You can have  Artistic Style format an entire file for you. It is a bit brittle, because you have to save the file before you run the external command.

You can bind a key stroke to the external command. Look at `Tools.ExternalCommandN` (where `N` is 1 to 24) in Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio supports external tools:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.EXTERNALTOOLS%29&rd=true

Configuring it with `$(ItemPath)` as Arguments works just fine. You can add other options in front of it like that: `-A12 $(ItemPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's now an "AStyle Extension" plugin for Visual Studio 2010/2012 that you can download and install via the built-in Visual Studio extension manager (Tools -> Extensions and Updates). It includes a configuration dialog that lets you control all the options.

There's more information on this plugin here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3f04cd-2866-4e47-a671-d1cc9cc3fb02